# How can I keep Gandhi satisfied? (He's a Peacekeeper and Nuke Happy )

Tags: civilization-6

I just started playing Civ 6 and I'm trying to play the agendas of the other leaders smartly, but I'm having trouble with one. In my current Gandhi has the following two agendas:

- Peacekeeper: Never declares war for which he can be branded a warmonger, and will try to befriend those who maintain peace. Hates warmongers.
- Nuke Happy: Has no hesitation to use nuclear weapons. Respects other civilizations that project strength with nuclear weapons.

These two agendas seem pretty at odd with each other and it seems when I try to keep satisfy one, the other agenda causes me to be denounced. So how can I keep Gandhi satisfied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend being a peace maker. Build a few nukes but don't use them.

By the way, these traits of Ghandi aren't particularly meant to work together well, but are tribute to a bug: [Why Ghandi is such an asshole in Civilization](http://kotaku.com/why-gandhi-is-such-an-asshole-in-civilization-1653818245) and [Gandhi is still an asshole in Civilization VI](http://kotaku.com/gandhi-is-still-an-asshole-in-civilization-vi-1788710568).

If you don't like his nuke trait, you could [remove it with a mod](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/remove-preferred-hidden-agendas.603555/#post-14542067).